# Build ASP.NET core application to target dot net core framework 1.1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

After upgrading from Visual Studio 2017 RC to the full release, the default .net core version which Visual Studio compiles for is 1.1.1.  This is version is not supported by the hosting provider that I use (given it isn't an LTS release), when deploying the stdout log file is:

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.1' was not found.
>
> - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>
>   C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
> - The following versions are installed:
>
>   1.0.0
>
>   1.0.1
>
>   1.1.0
> - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.1'.

So I would like to compile my existing project to 1.1.0, instead of 1.1.1.
I have tried targeting different build versions with the command line such as:

> dotnet build --framework netcoreapp1.1.0

Which isn't a known framework. Also I have tried adding SDK references to a global.json file which I added to my project, with no luck.
I also tried manually editing the csproj file to target different dot net core versions.
I have now installed every dot net core current and archived SDK available for download, but I can't find a valid way to build anything other than 1.1.1 or  1.0.

Previously I was able to build to version 1.1.0 with the VS 2017 RC.

Comment: Use [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-new) to generate a template then.

Comment: I have the same issue with dotnet new, you can specify either framework 1.0 or 1.1, the latter giving you 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` property in your .csproj.  This will tell the SDK to specifically target `1.1.0` instead of the implicit `1.1.1`.

See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726198/dotnet-build-to-specific-framework-version/42741291#42741291) on how to set this property automatically.